# How to calculate "weighted" Contribution to a goal?

Tags: percentages

I've searched and searched, and I'm not finding the answer to what I'm trying to find out. Possibly because I'm not asking the question correctly?

Let's pretend you run a team of door-to-door salespeople.
-You have 3 sales associates
-You have a route for tomorrow that has your team hitting 20 houses.
-At each house your team is responsible for selling 3 different widgets. (widget 1, widget 2, widget 3)

At the end of the day, we find that the team sold a total of 31 widgets:
SA1- Hit 8 houses and sold 16 Widgets
-6: Widget 1
-8: Widget 2
-2: Widget 3

SA2- Hit 5 houses and sold 6 Widgets
-1: Widget 1
-5: Widget 2
-0: Widget 3

SA3- Hit 7 houses and sold 9 Widgets
-4: Widget 1
-5: Widget 2
-0: Widget 3

Now, as the manager you want to break down their performance and celebrate your top performer. However, they visited different number of houses, so you can't just calculate their percent of contribution to the total goal, as the people that had more houses on their route have an advantage.

This is where I get stuck. I tried dividing their contribution percentage by the number of houses they visit, but it doesn't add to 100% (maybe it won't?) but I still don't feel like that is the answer. Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just compare each individual to themself. What is the maximum they can achieve? What did they actually achieve?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to use the "widgets per house" metric, the numbers will not add up. Here is the math behind it: Le's write the numbers ow widgets sold by associate $i$ as $W_i$, when he/she visited $H_i$ houses. Then the metric you are using is 
$$\frac{W_i}{H_i}$$
If we add these together we get $$\frac{W_1}{H_1}+\frac{W_2}{H_2}+\frac{W_3}{H_3}$$
But this is not the metric for the group, which is $$\frac{W_1+W_2+W_3}{H_1+H_2+H_3}$$